# Guardar configuración con IConfiguration .NET Core

Tags: c#, json, consola, .net-core

estoy dando mis primeros pasos con .NET Core.

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación de consola, en la que necesito manejar unas configuraciones sencillas, que deben poder ser seteadas por el usuario, pero también por el programa.

Por lo que decidí usar `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` y así manejar un archivo json a modo de configuración.

Creé un archivo json para probar (`appsettings.json`) con la siguiente estructura.

```
{
  "Mensaje":  "test"
}
```

Construyo el objeto `IConfiguration`

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
```

Luego, para leerlo, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
string msg = config["Mensaje"];
```

Dentro de msg, efectivamente se encuentra la palabra `test`.

Pero al intentar setear la configuración desde C#

```
config["Mensaje"] = "nuevo valor";
```

El archivo `appsettings.json` no se ve afectado en absoluto.

¿Cómo debo hacer para persistir el nuevo valor de la llave `Mensaje`?

Comment: Segun lo que he visto es algo no recomendado, los archivos de configuracion son archivos unicamente de lectura y no de escritura.

Answer (score 0):

para obtener el valor del mensaje se hace de otra forma con el objeto IConfiguration concretamente sería así: `configuration.GetSection("Mensaje")`, si el objeto Mensaje tuviera más niveles se haría de la siguiente forma: `configuration.GetSection("Mensaje:Nivel1")` y así sucesivamente para obtener la sección correspondiente de Json, por otra parte si es un objeto completo de más de un campo yo lo mapearía a C# inyectandolo en el configure service para tener el objeto de forma tipada, algo similar a esto:

ConfigureService -> Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<Config>(configuration.GetSection("Config"));
```

appSeting.json

```
"Config": {
"item1": "test1",
"item2": "test2",
"item3": "test3"
```

}

Clase Config.cs

```
public string Item1 { get; set;}
public string Item2 { get; set;}
public string Item3 { get; set;}
```

Y con eso ya podrías inyectar el objeto Config en cualquier parte de la aplicación, obtieniendo los valores que hay en el archivo appsetting.json